# Conditionally set expires headers in Apache config

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, http-headers, apache-config, mod-expires

I would like to conditionally set expires headers on images so that they will not cache while a project is in development but will when it is in production.  Ideally this would just be a modification of the apache conf file.  I have a perl script that will return the status of the project, which can be used with mod_rewrite as follows:

```
rewritemap  PSTAT prg:/bin/pstat.pl
...skipping...
rewritecond ${PSTAT:$site:$1} =devel
rewriterule ^/run/$site/p(\d+)/(\w+) /logout.pl/$2 [NS,L]
```

It would be nice if I could do something like:

```
rewritecond ${PSTAT:$site:$1} =devel
ExpiresByType image/jpg "now plus 1 second"
```

Though of course that wouldn't work.

Is there any solution?

Comment: Hey wait... does this question belong here or on ServerFault?

Comment: Cf. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38897706/conditionally-set-headers-in-apache-htaccess

Comment: Interesting! I wonder if that was a feature in 2011

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A trick that worked for me is to first set the headers unconditionally:

```
ExpiresByType image/jpg "now plus 1 second"
...
```

And then to unset the header in case we are in devel mode:

```
Header set Cache-control "no-cache" env=devel
Header unset expires env=devel
```

This requires that you have a boolean env `devel` previously initialized based on your mode. In our case we decide on the host name whether we want to be devel or not (devel.domain.com vs. www.domain.com).

Comment: Currently, we use the same URL for development and production, and the only way to know the difference is a MySQL database query (the reason for the perl script in the mod_rewrite) I'd really like not to change this; if it came down to that I think I'd just abandon this feature (no cache in development) instead (or change my backend scripts instead).  Still, this might be a piece of the solution, so upvoted.

Comment: I found an answer thanks to your response, so I'm accepting this and then adding the complete one as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from what alienhard said I managed to come up with an answer to my problem.

```
rewritemap  PSTAT prg:/bin/pstat.pl
...skipping...
rewritecond ${PSTAT:$site:$1} =devel
rewriterule ^/images/(\d+)/(\w+) - [E=devel:1]

header set cache-control "no-cache" env=devel
header unset expires env=devel
```

(`/images/(\d+)` is the folder of images for a particular project number `(\d+)`)

The `E` flag of `rewriterule` lets you set an environment variable in the case that the rule matches.  `-` doesn't actually rewrite anything.  Thus, this checks the output of the script using `rewritecond` sending it the project number from the `rewriterule`, and then sets the environment variable in the case that both conditions match.  Then `header` conditionally gets set based on the presence of that environment variable.