# Conditionally set headers in Apache htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a PHP Laravel application with a standard `.htaccess` file as follows.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

If the requested URL maps to a static file, it is served, and otherwise `index.php` is invoked. I need to add a set of headers for static files, which would kind of be the "else" of the last two conditions above. I need something like the below pseudo.

```
if static file
    Header set MyHeaderOne "something"
    Header set MyHeaderTwo "something"
end if
```

I can add the headers just fine, but got stuck at doing so conditionally. I looked a bit at `SetEnvIf`, which may make it possible.

So, how can I add some headers only for static files, i.e. if the requested file exists (e.g. `/images/example.jpg`)? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: What is your code for the static files that you have?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do a condition statement just like what you stated.

```
<If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ /\.(gif|jpe?g|png|css|js)$/">
  #put your header set stuff here
</If>
```

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html#examples

Comment: Wow, that seems obvious - not sure how I had missed that. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yep that's a nice new feature in 2.4

Comment: Whoa, that helped me a lot. Thanks for that. Because, if you use FilesMatch for this, it works even if the page gives 404 error. So that is not good, but this only works if the file exists.