# How to add conditions to htaccess or conf file for robots noindex

Tags: apache, .htaccess, httpd.conf

**Question 1**
I currently use the following to noindex a site in htaccess

```
Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex, follow"
```

I have tried all sorts of ways to noindex a pattern and am lost which is why I need help from you experts.

I would like to noindex /tags/ and /s/ and all pages within those categories.

**Question 2**

I also have another question which is related so I'll ask here instead of posting another question.

I have a number of aliases on a server and one htaccess file. How would I noindex a single URL such as https://www.website.com and allow the others to be indexed?

Can you help?

Comment: Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38897706/conditionally-set-headers-in-apache-htaccess

Comment: Thanks you for posting the link, I don't know why I couldn't find that through a Google search.

So I would need to do the following...

<If "%{HTTP_HOST} == 'website.com'">
    Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex, follow"
</If>

and 

<Directory "/tags">
    Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex, follow"
</Directory>

On the <Directory"/tags"> do I add a trailing slash? and how would I add in other directories?

Comment: If you're doing it in .htaccess file, use %{REQUEST_URI} as in the example in the page i sent you.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
 <IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
  SetEnvIf Request_URI "(*\/tags\/*|*\/p\/*)" x_tag=yes
  Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex, follow" env=x_tag
 </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```